# Range/Image of a Non-Decreasing Total Recursive Function is Recursive

Tags: logic, computability

How do I show that the range of a non-decreasing, total-recursive function is recursive? I've made reference to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709902/a-is-recursive-iff-a-is-the-range-of-an-increasing-function-which-is-recursive), but the method used there is not clear to me.

---

My attempt:

Let $f$ be a non-decreasing, total recursive function. Want to show $im(f)$ is recursive. That is, given any $a \in \mathbb{N}$, we want to show that there exists an algorithm that terminates in finite time and correctly decides whether or not $a \in im(f)$. In other words, we want a computable function $g$ such that $$g(a) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } a \in im(f)\\0\text{ if } a \notin im(f)\end{cases}$$
Then there are two possibilities: $im(f)$ is either finite or infinite. If $im(f)$ is finite, then the construction of $g$ is trivial: let $g = \sum_{i \in im(f)} \phi_a(i)$ where $phi_a$ is the indicator function:
$$\phi_a(i) = \begin{cases}1\text{ if } a=i\\0\text{ if } a \neq i\end{cases}$$
We note that $g$ will be either $1$ or $0$ because we assume the set $im(f)$ does not contain repeated elements.

Now suppose $im(f)$ is infinite. Then we can define a computable algorithm as such: for $n \in \mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, we compute $f(n)$. If $f(n) = a$, we terminate, returning that $a \in im(f)$, and we are done in finite time (since we required $n$ computations to achieve our result). If $f(n) > a$, we terminate, returning that $a \notin im(f)$, because $f$ is nondecreasing, so for all $x > n$, $f(x) > a$, so $\nexists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(N) = a$. Again, we will have terminated in finite time.

There is one further possibility: suppose that for all $N > n$, $f(N) = b < a$, i.e. $f$ becomes constant, and the algorithm as described just above will not terminate. However, then $im(f)$ is finite, and thereby computable. So in either case, there exists an algorithm that determines membership of $a \in im(f)$ in finite time (but we do not necessarily know which algorithm this is).

Comment: What have you tried?  Suppose I start enumerating an increasing list of numbers: 1, 2, 3, 7, 10 , 100, 1020, ... -- how would you tell whether 12,000 appears in the list?

Comment: @CarlMummert I would iterate through $x=0,1,2,\ldots$ until either $f(x) = 12000$ or $f(x) > 12000$?

Comment: Exactly. If the function is only assumed to be nondecreasing, that algorithm will still work as long as the range is unbounded. If the range is bounded, it's finite, so it will be computable but with a different algorithm.

Comment: @CarlMummert Sure, the intuition is pretty clear to me, but I'm having difficulty putting together an actual, reasonably rigorous proof. Give me two minutes and I will post what I have...

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm almost done. I proved much of it, apart from when $f$ just keeps returning the same value that is less than $a$ ---  then what do I do?

Comment: that is the interesting aspect of the proof. If the function is eventually constant, then the range is finite, and thus computable *a priori*. If the function is not eventually constant, then it will eventually take values larger than any given $a$. So you can prove an algorithm exists, but you may not know which algorithm it is.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks --- that was very helpful. I amended my proof in my original question. Does that look right to you?

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't understand your comment "$f$ is non-decreasing, so we can't assert $f(n) \geq n$". When did we assert this?

Comment: I misread a sentence. You have covered all the issues in your argument.